# How to find two matching cells using specefic indications and merge them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that look like the picture.

here some psudo-code  i wrote (not real code but it's what i think should work. maybe)

```
if comment = com#1 or com#2 then    ' com#1 is for missing Label 1 and com#2 is for missing Lable 2 
   save the row as row A
   find if there is a row that lable 1 or lable 2 == lable master then
   save the row as row B
        if NAME row A == NAME row B then 
             merge row A and row B
        end if 
   end if 
end if
```

if two rows are merged i want the to look like Label C

so my question: is there a way in vba to look for matching value and merge the matching values?

before :here i only want to merge the rows that have COM#1 and COM#2, if two rows have a match but have the same comment it must not merge.

[image]

after :

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQH8.png)

Comment: Can you give us a before/after example with this above table?

Comment: @dwirony there the before and after

Comment: Your example isn't specific enough - I could write a very simple macro to reproduce your above table, but I doubt it would work on your real data set like you'd expect. You haven't given an example where the test case is false - all rows above are merging - is that always going to be the outcome?

Comment: @dwirony i uploaded new picture. i hope it's clearer!

Comment: I still do not understand what the "matching" means...